# Sequenced Bone Movement with IK

Tags: bones, inverse-kinematics

yet another IK question....
I'm working on an animation project where I have an accordion wall segment that needs to extend outwards, one fold at a time. When I create the the IK bone setup and pull the outermost bone, all of the bones move at once which is not the desired affect. I have played around with animating stiffness values and IK constraints, but nothing is yielding the results I'm looking for.

Again, the desired affect is that when the accordion unfolds, only one segment will completely unfold at a time, and only when the extended accordion folds are all planar will it pull out another segment. (Bottom image, not top)

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Thank you AJCDFIN for the awesome help, I though I could take it from where you left it but I cannot.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution (Some description): I have 4 horizontal bones(small red one IK_Target), they all have a 'Limit Distance' constraint to each other. Moving IK_TRGT causes the bones to come out one at a time - that gets the action you require. The rest is just 2 sets of bones parented to each other(yellow to purple), yellow bones have IK targeting the purple bone in front of it which is parented to its corresponding larger horizontal bone. I have them all stacked on top each other when built, that can be fixed last to get some offset.Forgot to mention if this rig is going to traverse the Scene it will need a ParentBone to avoid unwanted transforms.
[image]

DISCLAIMER: This file created in v2.76 - If using 2.7x it will open fine,, If using 2.8x 'APPEND' the objects from the 'Object' folder.

[image]

Comment: Oh man, you rock! I was able to learn a lot more about how to set up IK bone constraints, so thank you for that!
I'm still struggling with the final steps of the animation, so any help on that would be greatly appreciated. I've got bones pointing where I want them, but I can't create the constraint that I'm looking for due to circular reference. Please see the attached updates to the original question, if you have the time.

Comment: Ah...ok, are you wanting the whole thing to do that or just the very last section ??

Comment: Just the last segment. Your example is exactly what I need to get to step 2, but the very end should look like steps 2, 3, and final. I tried to parent your rig to the purple bone which follows the correct path, but the the motion is all messed up because of the circular reference. I tried adding additional armatures, but still ran into circular references. I'm not sure how to go about setting this problem up.

Comment: Hey, I am not able to come up with a logical solution, all my attempts break the first parts or don't work for the last part - sorry

Comment: No worries, thank you again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well not 100% what I was looking for, but I was able to get around the circular reference by parenting the rig [AJCDFIN](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/53148/ajcdfin) created to another rig that tracks an empty, rather than the IK target of the first rig.

[image]

If anyone is interested here is the file:

[image]